# TranslateY based on width of object

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a quick question about transforms, more specifically about translation. I have a div that I have rotated 90degrees, and I want to translate it on the X-axis, however I want to translate it as much as the length of the height of the text. What I mean by this is, the div that I am currently dealing with is sideways. If the height is 200px and the width is 300px (it's not, just want to help make it easier to visualize, I don't know the height of the div as there is text in it), I want to translate the div 200px to the right.

I understand that if I used translateX or Y with percentages, it would translate based on the percentage of the width or height, respectively, however I was wondering how I could inverse it. Thanks a lot in advanced!

Comment: it's clear that you cannot inverse but you need to think differently and explain what you need to have at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done with javascript.
Get element actual height: `var height = document.getElementById("someId").clientHeight;` and set it as value to transform property: `element.style.transform = translateY('${height}')`

note: used [temlpate literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to put variable inside string

Comment: Hmm, yeah I figured there was probably a way to do it with javascript, wanted to test out my luck with CSS first for consistency, but will try this out. Thank you!